# Insert a new column in pandas with random string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, series

I had a DataFrame

```
     A B C
   0 1 2 3  
   1 2 3 3  
   2 3 2 1
```

I needed to create a new column in a pandas DataFrame with 'yes' or 'no' randomly filling this column.

```
     A B C  NEW
   0 1 2 3  yes
   1 2 3 3  no
   2 3 2 1  no
```

Using random.choice results in a column with the same result for every line

```
     A B C  NEW
   0 1 2 3  no
   1 2 3 3  no
   2 3 2 1  no
```

I tried map, apply and applymap but there's a easier way to do.

Comment: `np.random.choice(['yes','no'],len(df))` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must set the new column to `pd.Series` then use `random.choices:`

```
import random

df['NEW'] = pd.Series(
    random.choices(['yes', 'no'], weights=[1, 1], k=len(df)), 
    index=df.index
)
```

`random.choices` will pick up one of this values for every line.

`weights` sets probabilities for pickin 'yes' or 'no', respectively. If you desire a higher chance for 'yes' i.e, you must increase the first number.

`k` sets the length of the Series. It must have the same length of DataFrame.

`index` is important to set as the same as `df.index` otherwise it can fill with NaN whether you have sliced it from a bigger DataFrame